# Possible to force router to route internally?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, router

I have many network drives mounted on my mac and am constantly having to disconnect and reconnect when i leave my apartment and work remotely because of the speed issues.

Since I am on a cable modem, I have [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) set up to ensure I only have to remember one address when the IP address changes.

When i connect to my [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) address on my local network, the connection seems to route somewhere outside my LAN and transfer speeds to my server are MUCH slower than just connecting to the servers local IP address instead.

> **Is it possible to tell my router "if connecting to the [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/)
>   address when on the internal network
>   DO NOT route outside the LAN?**

If it helps to know, my router is running the linux based DD-WRT firmware.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the DynDNS address on your local network?

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes and no.

The Dyndns address is an external address: that's the whole point. It points to your external interface, the one out there on teh interwebs, not your internal one on your nice safe lan. So if something from your internal network is pointed at that address, it goes out, turns around, and comes back in. That's the only way it knows to get there, the only valid route attached to the url.

The quick and dirty fix is to put an entry into your HOSTS file pointing the dyndns url to the local ip address of that machine. You'll have to do it for every local machine, and it'll absolutely break everything every time you leave the apartment, so you'll have to keep changing it.

The more complex fix is to set up your own local DNS, and override the record locally. Then, if you connect via DHCP, and let the DNS be automatically assigned, you'll always have the correct address.

Answer (score 0):

The extension to @Satanicpuppy's more complex fix suggestion is to get some sort of VPN solution for working remotely (consulting?) so that you point your VPN client to the DynDNS address and let your in-apartment DNS server handle which machines are which.  That does take some doing but is definitely the way to go if you're expanding or if you are just looking for a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to setup an internal DNS server and you're able to use DHCP everywhere you go, it's pretty easy.  Setup the internal DNS server to point to the local address and leave dyndns pointing to the outside address!